# template_redirect not working, apparently for no reason

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

Well I made a plugin that uses `template_redirect` for the custom post type `squeezepages` and it works all fine and dandy, but I copied the exact same code, put it in a new plugin, activated it (with a few minor adjustments, for example I changed the custom post type to `newpages` and the `template_redirect` is taking the template from a different source) and suddenly it doesn't work?

I can have both plugins active at the same time, the squeeze pages work, the new pages don't. It puzzles me so much. I even disabled the squeeze pages plugin and it still doesn't work. I've tried all combinations (there's only a couple) and still nothing. It seems like it's not working for NO reason. I've been staring at the same code for 2 hours and I'm not able to figure it out.

Here's the code for my custom post types:

```
add_action( 'init', 'ifp_create_post_type' );
function ifp_create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'newpages',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'New Pages' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'New Page' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'newpage', 'with_front' => FALSE),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'page-attributes')
    )
);
}
```

And my `template_redirect`:

```
function ifp_default_template() {
    if(get_post_type() == 'newpages') : global $wp_query, $post, $posts;
    include(PLUGINDIR . '/newpage/themes/default.php');
    exit; endif;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'ifp_default_template');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I needed to put `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` after my `register_post_type` function. The reason it wasn't working is because it was returning the page with a 404 error, so I figured out it was a permalinks problem and the code above solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not much code here... Let's break it down into things that can go wrong:

1. Verify that `ifp_default_template()`is firing (for example earlier redirect could include 
   another template and dies, never reaching it).
2. Verify that `get_post_type()` returns expected value.
3. Verify that include path is being generated correctly (I'd use [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url), it's more robust than building path from strings).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out that it is returning the post type as `post` and not `newpages` - why would it be doing that?

Comment: @Jared dump global `$post` and see what it holds. `get_post_type()` pretty much returns `post_type` field from it (with few sanity checks on top).

Comment: It's still returning the post type as `post` after removing `global $post;`. Could it have to do with `register_post_type`?

Comment: `get_post_type` is [for use inside the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type), according to the docs.